# Поиск в файлах в windows

Tags: windows, файлы, полнотекстовый-поиск

Подскажите бесплатный софт, который работает под ОС windows и наделен функционалом поиска слова во всех файлах указанной папки.
Желательно user friendly, но и консольная программа тоже подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

В windows имеется встроенный функционал по данному вопросу. Ознакомьтесь [http://ru.wikihow.com/искать-файл-по-содержимому-в--Windows-7](http://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2--Windows-7)

Comment: К сожалению стоит windows XP, встроенный не подходит, кто пользовался знает, что он тупит и не работает...

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V могу только вот эту фиксу посоветовать, https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/309173

Comment: FAR используйте...